# Grep- Search exiftool output for different matches

Tags: bash, grep, exiftool

I have a large folder tree, and would like to make a script to open up gThumb or some other image viewer based on a keyword search.  `exiftool` is already installed on my system. and the command

```
exiftool -a -r -G1 -s $FILE
```

prints the data out in format

```
[ExifTool]      ExifToolVersion                 : 8.60
[System]        FileName                        : 4-4_wlax_0127.jpg
[System]        Directory                       : .
[System]        FileSize                        : 6.3 MB
[System]        FileModifyDate                  : 2012:04:05 13:57:54-04:00
[System]        FilePermissions                 : rwxrwxrwx
```

Currently,

```
exiftool -a -r -G1 -s . | grep Keywords | grep "$1*"
```

prints out the Keyword row of the metadata as

```
[IPTC]          Keywords                        : 2012, Womens Lax, ..., ...
```

where `$1` is the keyword search value. Right now, my solution is to use two loops, each executing an `exiftool` call for a different grep value.  How can I excute a single `exiftool` call that for matching keywords, the associated filename is passed to a list.

EDIT- Clarification:

If a match exits to the Keyword field, I want to print out the FileName row.  However, Keyword exists ~20 lines below FileName in the text output.

Comment: Do you want to print "the FileName row" or just the filename?

Comment: @Johnsyweb,  my thinking was to output the FileName row to awk to print out the appropriate column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), rather than all those pipes!

```
% exiftool -a -r -G1 -s . | awk -v search='your search string here' '
    $2 ~ /FileName/ { filename = $0 }
    $2 ~ /Keywords/ && $0 ~ search { print filename }
'
```

This assumes that `Filename` always appears before `Keywords` for each file processed. If you have multiple strings you wish to search for, just pipe-separate them (it's a regular expression!):

```
% exiftool -a -r -G1 -s . | awk -v search='first|second' '
    $2 ~ /FileName/ { filename = $0 }
    $2 ~ /Keywords/ && $0 ~ search { print filename }
'
```

If you *just* want the filenames (and not the entire row), perhaps this is a neater solution:

```
% exiftool -a -r -G1 -s . | awk -F': ' -v search='first|second|third' '
    $1 ~ /FileName/ { filename = $2 }
    $1 ~ /Keywords/ && $2 ~ search { print filename }
'
```

You can also do all of your text processing in the same program, of course.

Comment: How does `awk` handle the multiple keywords problem? Can he do keyword1|keyword2 like this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the exiftool -if option:

exiftool -filename -s3 -if '$keywords=~/some keyword/' .

Comment: Thanks for responding, I completely missed that option.  Piping the output to `grep Filename | awk '{print $2}'` did the trick along with adding the `-r` flag.

Comment: But with -filename and -s3 too, you shouldn't need to use awk.  The ExifTool output options are so flexible there should never be any need to use awk at all.

Comment: don't get your cmd totally.. what is the sense of the s13? and how it is possible to process the selected files to open it in a another application? Your answer looks like that everything should possible :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you have multiple keywords your want to filter for. Use `egrep` and the `|`-operator:

```
exiftool -a -r -G1 -s . | grep Keywords | egrep "$1|$2"
```

whereas $1 is the first keyword and $2 is the second one. `egrep` can be replace with `grep -E` as `egrep` is deprecated.

EDIT (after question has actually changed): You should have made a new question.

You could make a loop over all files and if a file matches one of your keywords you use it. E.g.:

```
for n in `ls`; do
    c=`exiftool -a -G1 -s $n | grep Keywords | egrep "$1|$2" | wc -l`
    if [ $c -gt 0 ]; then
         echo $n has matched
    fi
done
```

Comment: Almost.  The output is on multiple lines, where Keyword is about 20 rows below Filename, which is line 2 of output.  If there is a match to the Keyword, I want to print the FileName.